# Default endpoint in esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.0.0. when i have started with these server their was less load on servers as their are less no of services.but now situation changes.Their are no of services on server and each proxy contain particular address endpoint of dss. After calling this address endpoint it navigate to that endpoint and retrieve information and give the response. This is general scenario of all the service.

Day by day no of services increases and due to the load the server getting slower. That's why i wish to create a particular default endpoint from where i can call the service easily. No need to call the address endpoint and all. Is it possible? how can i implement this?
for load balancing i have used Amazon AWS Elastic Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. For all proxy services your endpoints are different or not? I mean, all different endpoints calling same dataservice or different. If they are different, you need to have different endpoints. If all endpoints point same dataservice, then you do not need to have multiple copy of same endpoint. Define only one endpoint and use that in all proxyservices. When you define proxy service there is a option to define endpoint, where select the existing predefined endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Ratha for reply. Right now i have separate endpoint for each service. n i wish do set a default endpoint for all service.If i call that endpoint then all services should call once

Comment: Then i think you need to refer Recipient endpoint, which is used to  to send a same request to multiple endpoints.